# Selenium + Java = How to click on a button related to an specific span class?

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath

Hope you can help me,
I need to click on a size button (related to shoes' size), but selenium is not able to find it with its xpath:

`html/body/div[4]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/form[1]/div[4]/ul/li[5]/label/span`

So I would like to know if I can get it somehow through its span class:

`<span class="attr-name">42</span>`

This span class is in a tree of a lot of divs

(ps: I would really like to post an image, but is saying I do not have enough reputation)

Comment: Learn XPath. You can simply search by class `//span[@class='class']` for example.

Comment: Boris, could you check again? now I've edited because I notice the span class wasn't being displayed

Comment: Can you use CSS Selectors?  You could try `span[class='attr-name']` or more succinctly: `By.cssSelector(".attr-name")`

Comment: But how do I do that? There's a lot of span class="attr-name", but they vary from 35 to 42. I wan't to select the one related to 42. How do I write it? I do not have idea how to deal with css =/

Comment: Oh yeah, I got it!

I used the following xpath:

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'attr-name') and text() = '41']")).click();